# Can two threads write to the same place without synchronization?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

My code does some processing, and it writes intermediate results into an array, which I can later write to file. I want to break it into threads, but their processing regions will overlap, so some intermediate results will be written twice. Both threads will write the same value to the same array element.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int array[4];

void f1()
{
    array[0] = 10;
    array[1] = 11;
}

void f2()
{
    array[1] = 11;
    array[2] = 12;
}

void f3()
{
    array[2] = 12;
    array[3] = 13;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f1);
    std::thread t2(f2);
    std::thread t3(f3);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    for (int x: array)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

This code outputs the expected result (`10 11 12 13`). But is this guaranteed, or does it have undefined behavior? Do I need to protect some array elements with mutexes or anything else, so they are only ever written once?

Comment: UB: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races

Comment: Simplest way to fix this is to have an array of `atomic<int>` and use one of the weaker memory orders.

Comment: writing the same value does not help, because writing to an `int` is not (necessarily) atomic

Comment: @idclev463035818 even if `int` is not atomic (artificial example: the n bytes of the `int` are written separately) what could go wrong if the values written are the same?

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok, not being atomic isnt the point. The point is just that the standard says that it is UB

Comment: @Jabberwocky "may be written" not "are written" - most processors have instructions to write an integer in a single operation.

Comment: @AdrianCornish yes of course, that's why I wrote _artificial example_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Re, "what could go wrong if..." The _official_ answer to that is, _anything_ could go wrong.\* If you need to convince somebody that your program actually is correct, and not just that it happens to work on this particular hardware, and this particular operating system, and under this particular phase of the Moon; then writing it in strict accordance with the standard is a good first step.

Comment: \* Don't underestimate the power of pernicious compiler writers to invent new optimizations that seemingly are designed to cause as much havoc as possible when your program breaks the rules.

Comment: Sorry for necroing this, but:
there is the commonly accepted strict interpretation of the standard, which forbids writing the same value from two threads.
However, there could be an even stricter interpretation of the standard, which allows such a program. This interpretation comes from the curious fact, that the standard uses the word "modify" instead of the more common "write" in exact this clause (6.9.2.2 afaik). Then one thread writes and the other thread... neither reads nor modifies the variable. 
So the question is: why does the standard use "modify" instead of "write"?